# What driver should I use when trying to open a Geospatial PDF with OSGEO and Python?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

My code is as follows:

```
from osgeo import ogr  
from osgeo import gdal

dso = ogr.Open('myfile.pdf')
print dso

dsg = gdal.Open('myfile.pdf')
print dsg

driverGeoPDFogr = ogr.GetDriverByName('PDF')
dso2 = driverGeoPDFogr.Open('myfile.pdf')
print dso2
```

This results in:

```
None
ERROR 4: `myfile.pdf' not recognised as a supported file format.

None
None
```

I know the file is a valid file, and when running gdalinfo from command line, the result for driver is:

```
Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF
```

My question is, is PDF the incorrect driver name here for Geospatial PDF, or is this file format incompatible here?  I'm running Python 2.6 and GDAL 1.11.2.  Note, this is a Geospatial PDF, NOT a GeoPDF.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you should try to open PDF with a raster driver.

Comment: The PDF is vector so I do not believe that a raster driver will work

Comment: Well, it is somewhere in the middle and when creating pdf files GDAL used to use a raster driver and ogr driver somehow together. But drivers may be unified now.

Comment: You wrote yourself that you checked the driver with gdalinfo. What does ogrinfo report?

Comment: `ogrinfo` results in: 

`Had to open data source read-only. INFO: Open of 'myfile.pdf' using driver 'PDF' successful.`

Comment: I also looped through every available ogr driver, attempting to open the PDF with each ogr driver, and each driver resulted in "None"

Comment: @js1983 got this working somehow eventually?